# Difference for bean id on the spring context

Tags: java, spring

Is there any differences between these two following bean id definition in spring context

```
<bean id="merging.Article" class="com.qtl.everest.data.merge.UftMergingService">
```

&

```
<bean id="mergingArticle" class="com.qtl.everest.data.merge.UftMergingService">
```

Here first one is just separated with '.' operator and second one is not but only in camel case. So putting dot with bean id definition really meant something variation on their functionalities.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Id is just for referring bean. No difference you can choose any name you like

Comment: they would do the same thing(as they refer to the same class) but can be referenced with different names mentioned(with dot and without).

Answer (score 0):

these are two not `equal()` `String` so it is different

Answer (score 0):

> id

is just a unique name you provide to access the bean, it depends on your coding practices what you really need to follow.
In your case no difference both are just two different unique id's.